unresolved external symbol IID_IADs?
I'm trying out the sample program below, but it won't link because of unresolved external symbol for both IID_IADs and IID_IADsContainer.
What library am I support to include to resolve that?
#include <windows.h>
#include <activeds.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Activeds.lib")

int main() {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize COM library." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IADsContainer* pContainer = NULL;
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com", NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADsContainer, (void**)&pContainer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind to Active Directory." << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IEnumVARIANT* pEnum = NULL;
    hr = ADsBuildEnumerator(pContainer, &pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get enumerator." << std::endl;
        pContainer->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    VARIANT var;
    ULONG lFetch;
    IDispatch* pDispatch = NULL;
    IADs* pADs = NULL;
    BSTR bstrClass;

    while (S_OK == ADsEnumerateNext(pEnum, 1, &var, &lFetch)) {
        pDispatch = V_DISPATCH(&var);
        hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IADs, (void**)&pADs);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = pADs->get_Class(&bstrClass);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                if (_wcsicmp(bstrClass, L"computer") == 0) {
                    BSTR bstrName;
                    hr = pADs->get_Name(&bstrName);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                        std::wcout << L"Computer: " << bstrName << std::endl;
                        SysFreeString(bstrName);
                    }
                }
                SysFreeString(bstrClass);
            }
            pADs->Release();
        }
        VariantClear(&var);
    }

    ADsFreeEnumerator(pEnum);
    pContainer->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}


use __uuidof(IADsContainer) and __uuidof(IADs). or link with ADSIid.Lib , but better use __uuiodf

@RbMm using __uuidof complains error C2787: '_GUID': no GUID has been associated with this object
error C2660: 'ADsOpenObject': function does not take 5 arguments
error C2787: '_GUID': no GUID has been associated with this object ... but linking with ADSIid.lib worked (how did you find that?)

The sample program doesn't list any computers anyway ...

what compiler you use ? the IID_PPV_ARGS(&pContainer) instead IID_IADsContainer, (void**)&pContainer must work on CL(msvc). IID_PPV_ARGS(&pContainer) equal to __uuidof(IADsContainer), (void**)&pContainer

that program doesn't list any computers anyway is already absolute another question. how did you find that (ADSIid.lib) ? are this is not trivial, if bit think ?

It works with WinNT instead of LDAP.  VS2022 I used to build.

VS2022 I used to build - c or c++ ? msvc or clang ? (msvc support both). if msvc c++ - __uuidof(IADsContainer), (void**)&pContainer or IID_PPV_ARGS(&pContainer) must work. probably you use c

I'm pretty confident that a C compiler would reject std::cout << "whatever"; because it is not valid C.

@user3161924 "linking with ADSIid.lib worked (how did you find that?)" - Did you read the documentation? Setting Up Visual C++ 6.0 for ADSI Development

c++ 14 module, msvc, __uuidof didn't work, linking with adsiid.lib did.

@RemyLebeau pointed out the correct solution, Setting Up the Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Development Environment.


Point to the include and library directory. Select Tools | Options. Click the Directory tab, and specify the path to the ADSI
header files.
Include the Activeds.h file in your project.
Add the Activeds.lib and Adsiid.lib files to the linker input for
your project.


